# Happy One Year Anniversary!

Tags: discussion

Albeit I'm **slightly** early, I want to congratulate everyone on an awesome first year.

Here's hoping to a good second year, and hopefully a graduation to full site status!

Comment: Graduation is not too far, we will reach it soon.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Yayyyyyyyyy

Answer (score 10):

Since 2012 was a leap year I guess this is the **official anniversary picture!**

[image]

Looks very cute, doesn't it?

Answer (score 8):

I cannot believe its been a year. Thank you all for making this a great site.

Answer (score 7):

On complition of one year Our [ratings](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698?page=2&phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top) is:

**5.3 questions per day** - **Okay** – 15 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work. A healthy site generates lots of good content to make sure users keep coming back.

**95% answered - Excellent** – 90% answered is a healthy beta, 80% answered needs some work. In the beta it's especially important that when new visitors ask questions they usually get a good answer.

**233 avid users 2,387 total users Excellent –** Every site needs a solid group of core users to assist in moderating the site. We recommend:
150 users with 200+ rep (currently 233 users with 200+ rep)
10 users with 2,000+ rep (currently 20 users with 2,000+ rep)
5 users with 3,000+ rep (currently 10 users with 3,000+ rep)

**1.7 answer ratio Okay –** 2.5 answers per question is good, only 1 answer per question needs some work. In a healthy site, questions receive multiple answers and the best answer is voted to the top.

**5,389 visits/day Excellent –** 1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day needs some work. A great site benefits people outside the community. Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come from search engines.

Its a good sigh,we are in improving state.We will soon graduate to full site.

Answer (score 6):

[Happy Anniversary!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knp9-GY6fHE)

Answer (score 5):

Happy anniversary to all my enthusiast, movie maniac friends. I am pretty sure the site is not far from graduation. :)